# Foreach loop only returns one data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreach

I have the following code where it should loop through each Schedule for the Staff in order to compare the date and time.

In my current situation, I have 3 rows/schedules for the same Staff but foreach loop only takes one row to compare. For this reason, I'm getting the wrong result.

I also tried to use nested foreach loop but I was receiving duplicated results.
Tom was displayed 2 times. Bryan and Tim were not included.

**Example:**
In Staff table I have 4 members:

1. Alex
2. Tom
3. Bryan
4. Tim

In Scheduler Template I have the following:

1. **Alex** **>** 01 Aug 2017 **>** 09:55 - 10:55 - Owner
2. **Tom**  **>** 01 Aug 2017 **>** 10:10 - 11:10
3. **Tom**  **>** 01 Aug 2017 **>** 13:45 - 14:45
4. **Tom**  **>** 01 Aug 2017 **>** 15:30 - 16:30

Alex is the owner of the selected schedule who wants to transfer it to another available staff member. So, this Alex should not be displayed in the list.

Tom has 3 appointments on the same day as the selected schedule date and he is not available between 09:55 - 10:55 because he is busy between 10:10 and 11:10. For this reason the result should display Bryan and Tim only.

In the code below, since my code is not looping through Tom's other appointments, I get him in the list because my code only takes 15:30 and it takes is as an available staff member.

**Entity**
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5300584578130c39413784d2e3c2f7d4

```
var selectedSchedule = await db.SchedulerTemplate.FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.SchedulerTemplateId == stid);
var startTime = selectedSchedule.Time;
var endTime = selectedSchedule.Time.AddMinutes(selectedSchedule.Duration);

var staff = await db.Staff.Where(x => x.Deleted == false).Select(c => new TransferViewModel()
{
    UserId = c.UserId,
    FullName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName,
}).ToListAsync();

var staffList = new List<TransferViewModel>();

foreach (var s in staff)
{
    if (selectedSchedule.ForUserId != s.UserId)
    {
        var staffSchedule = await db.SchedulerTemplate.FirstOrDefaultAsync(
        ss => ss.Date == selectedSchedule.Date && ss.ForUserId == s.UserId && ss.Deleted == false);

        if (staffSchedule != null)
        {
            var st = staffSchedule.Time;
            var et = st.AddMinutes(staffSchedule.Duration);

            if (! (startTime.TimeOfDay < et.TimeOfDay && st.TimeOfDay < endTime.TimeOfDay))
            {
                staffList.Add(s);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            staffList.Add(s);
        }
    }
}

ViewData["availableStaff"] = staffList;
```

Am I missing something in the code above?

Comment: I can only suggest you to use the debugger and check if the variables have effectively the values you assume they have. In this way you will be able to see the code flow and understand what's going wrong. We don't have your data and we cannot reproduce your problem

Comment: @Steve Thanks, I have done this by putting breakpoints. Inside foreach, staffSchedule only reads one data.

Comment: I complettely agree Steve. If you can´t debug your issue, how and *why* should we? We have far less knowledge on your data than yourself, so you should try to debug the issue and see what happens with the data. Start this by showing wha´s in `staff`. I assume as you´re asynchronously query your data `staff` contains just one single element.

Comment: *staffSchedule only reads one data* -  you are using `FirstOrDefaultAsync` so you will get the first one.

Comment: @OfirWinegarten but it's inside Foreach loop!

Comment: *I have 3 rows/schedules for the same Staff*  - if its the same staff then you should have a foreach also for the `staffSchedule` and not take the first one.

Comment: Please clearly explain your sample inputs, expected outputs and current (actual) outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping through the staff members but not querying correctly their schedules.

You can change your query to include all relevant business logic and get rid of the `if` statement.

*Since i'm not sure about getting the `TimeOfDay` through entity framework, i'm calling `ToList` after the first query to materialize it first and then we can use linq-to-object which supports it.*

So, Instead of the `FirstOrDefault` we'll use `Where` to get all records, and then validate that all of them are not within the time frame.

```
bool isAvailable = await db.SchedulerTemplate
    .Where(ss => ss.Date == selectedSchedule.Date && ss.ForUserId == s.UserId && ss.Deleted == false)
    .ToList()
    .All(ss=> !(startTime.TimeOfDay < ss.Time.AddMinutes(staffSchedule.Duration).TimeOfDay && ss.Time.TimeOfDay < endTime.TimeOfDay))

if (isAvailable)
{
    staffList.Add(s);
}
```

Comment: תודה! your solution is awesome. It's short and sweet. Thank you again.